# Hibernate: column does not exist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

When I try to load an Entity with Hibernate I get the following error in postgres-log:

```
ERROR: column appuser0_.device_token does not exist at character 35
STATEMENT:  select appuser0_.id as id1_27_0_, appuser0_.device_token as device_t2_27_0_,....
```

The column device_token definitely exists - and if I copy-paste the whole logged statement and execute it in PGAdmin, I get the expected result.

So what do I forget? What is the difference between the Hibernate statement and the manually executed one?

Comment: please post your entity code and ddl for related table

Answer (score 2):

This issue was caused by the multi tenant configuration so that the wrong DataSource has been chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you defined the query, the problem might be located somewhere else: For example, HQL Queries are using the "property-names" of the class, not the column names.

And if you have something like:

```
@Column("device_token")
private String deviceToken;
```

Then your HQL-Query should target "deviceToken" and not "device_token". We also encountered a similar error once: Hibernate was reporting "user_id" is missing, because we named the property "userId" with the underscored version for the column name only.

This might be not the problem for you but worth double checking it.

Comment: deviceToken is defined as you proposed and the Query is done via Spring JPA which uses Hibernate with ImprovedNamingStrategy. The column in the database is named "device_token". Just to try it out I renamed the variable to "device_token" - but no effect. Interesting to notice: It doesn't matter if the columnname is "devicetoken" or "device_token" (with corresponding naming in @Column-annotation) - the error remains the same, "ERROR: column appuser0_.devicetoken does not exist" respectively